# Tired parents and happy kids lives here

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I saw many plates with such sentence, but isn't grammatically incorrect to use "lives"? Shouldn't it be just "live"?

[image: Sign with text "Tired parents and happy kids lives here"]

Comment: What do actually mean by: I saw **many** plates? I have never ever seen a plaque like that with that mistake....That is a mistake, from a Swedish company:https://www.tradera.com/item/2935/342993127/emaljskylt-tired-parents-and-happy-kids-lives-here-

Comment: @Lambie, perhaps the OP lives over there, and that's why they saw so **many** ?

Comment: @LucianSava He or she should have provided a link. Also, it's the same picture repeated over and over in Google images.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct. Don't buy that sign. Buy this one instead:

[image]

It's grammatically correct, and the line break is more aesthetic.

Comment: So, that's what you selling? :)

Comment: @Lambie - English enthusiasts and laughing readers jokes here.

Comment: It sounds like the opening of a joke *"... but not at the same time"*